# how to remove duplicates if two columns are equal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

dataframe is

```
View              player  country
Admin_Case_View  ckear    USA
Admin_Case_View  ckear  
Admin_Case_View  ckear  
Admin_Questions  jungeunk  KOR
Admin_Questions  jungeunk
```

if `view == player` , then remove duplicates and where place is empty in country column.

required output should be

```
View              player  country
Admin_Case_View  ckear    USA   
Admin_Questions  jungeunk  KOR
```

Comment: `df.dropna()` is the solution you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
df.dropna(subset=['country']).drop_duplicates(subset=['View', 'player'])
```

should do the trick if I understood correctly.